# Print statements inside overridden methods not appearing

Tags: java, inheritance

So I am pretty stuck. I have some code that is being using inside my main method which  needs to override the given methods and print out a statement. I got the statement in `offer(E s)` to work, but can't seem to get the statements in `peek()` and `size()` to print. They are functioning properly, but the statements "Peeking at list" and "Reporting list size" just won't print in their methods. If some people can shed some light it would be greatly appreciated! The main is located in a separate file

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*; //for Point

public class StudentList<E>extends LinkedList<E> {
    public boolean offer(E s) {
        super.offer(s); 
        System.out.println("Offering "+ s);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        super.contains(o);
        return false;
    }

    public E peek(E slist){
        super.peek();
        System.out.println("Peeking at list") ;
        return slist;
    }

    public int size(Integer ilist){
        System.out.println("Reporting list size");
        size(ilist);
        //System.out.println("Reporting list size");
        return ilist;
    }
}
```

Here is the main method:

```
public class OfferDriver
{
    public static void main ( String[] args) 
    {
        StudentList<Integer> ilist = new StudentList<Integer>( );
        StudentList<String> slist = new StudentList<String>( );

        String s;
        Integer i;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a word to offer (\"stop\" to stop):\t");
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            s = in.next();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) { break; }
                slist.offer(s);
                System.out.println("Size is: " + slist.size());
                System.out.print("Please enter a word to offer (\"stop\" to stop):\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + slist);
            String si = slist.peek();
            System.out.println("Testing peek(): " + si); 

            System.out.print("Please enter an integer to offer (<any word> to stop):\t");
            while (in.hasNextInt()) {
                i = in.nextInt();
                ilist.offer(i);
                System.out.println("Size is: " + ilist.size());
                System.out.print("Please enter an integer to offer (<any word> to stop):\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n" + ilist);
            int pi = ilist.peek();
            System.out.println("Testing peek(): " + pi);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `peek` and `size` methods are not called. You can always check that with the help of a debugger. You seems to be wrongly overriding the methods. So try adding `@override` on top of your methods.

LinkedList [peek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#peek()) method does not take any param but your method does:

```
public E peek(E slist)
```

so it means that you are not overriding the method.

Answer (score 0):

`peek()` is not the same as `peek(E)` that you have implemented.

You have defined `peek` within your `StduentList` as

```
public E peek(E slist) {
```

But are using

```
String si = slist.peek();
```

To call it...

In fact, I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why you need to override any of the methods in the first place...

Comment: It is apart of an assignment, so I did try erasing my parameters at one point but it gave me an error about the method needing to return type E. What does that mean?

Comment: So because super.peek is of type E because of LinkedList, it can just be returned like that?

Comment: You defined `StudentList` to contain objects of type `E`, so it's guaranteed to always contain objects of type `E`.  So far, you've done nothing that `LinkedList` does by default, hence my comment about needing extend or override the methods....

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the peek() and size() in main, you called this method from

```
     String java.util.LinkedList.peek()
      int java.util.LinkedList.size()
```

this are not your method, which you write in your StudentList Class.